# Outlook Add-in takes a long time for receiving items from Outlook

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop, outlook-addin

We have two machines with the same configuration, the both machines have outlook 2010.
The both Outlooks have the same contacts list (2769 contacts on First and Second)

On the First machine it takes about 12.5 minutes to receive all contacts.

> 6/8/2017 10:33:02 AM -- Receiving Contacts 
>   6/8/2017 10:45:34 AM -- Found 2769 contacts in Outlook

On the Second machine it takes about 45 seconds to receive all contacts.

> 6/8/2017 10:54:46 AM -- Receiving Contacts 
>   6/8/2017 10:55:33 AM -- Found 2769 contacts in Outlook

Code that pulls the contacts from outlook looks like following:

```
Items items1 = _contactFolder.Items;
ArrayList list1 = new ArrayList();
for (int num1 = 1; num1 <= items1.Count; num1++)
{
    ContactItem item1 = null;
    try
    {
        item1 = (ContactItem) items1.Item(num1);
    }
    catch
    {
        goto Label_01;
    }
    if (item1.MessageClass.StartsWith("IPM.Contact"))
    {
        Contact contact1 = new Contact();
        contact1.Account = item1.Account;
        contact1.Anniversary = item1.Anniversary;
        contact1.AssistantName = item1.AssistantName;
        contact1.AssistantTelephoneNumber = item1.AssistantTelephoneNumber;
        ......
        contact1.LastModificationTime = item1.LastModificationTime;
        contact1.EntryID = item1.EntryID;
        list1.Add(contact1);
    }
    Label_01:;              
    Utils.FreeComObject(item1);
    item1 = null;
}
Utils.FreeComObject(items1);
items1 = null;
```

Can someone tell me what can be causing of so long receiving items from outlook on First machine? any idea how to speed up it

Comment: Have you verified which specific part of the code has the increased latency? (A finally {} would remove the need for a goto label btw)

Comment: @Alex K., I have not verified it yet. I've found out that PST file of first machine has big size (33 Gb), however PST file of second machine has non small size as well (12 GB) but second outlook works quickly. I want to compact the PST file of first machine and check if it help. If not, will measure time.